# How to make polymorphic jackson serialization working with map

Tags: java, json, jackson

I try to have Jackson property type info serialized, even when my type is referenced by a map.

With this simple sample:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeName;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class DemoJackson {
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY)
    public static abstract class Animal {}

    @JsonTypeName("cat")
    public static class Cat extends Animal {}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Cat cat = new Cat();
        System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(cat));

        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("data", cat);

        System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(map));
    }
}
```

I get:

```
{"@type":"cat"}
{"data":{}}
```

But I would like to have:

```
{"@type":"cat"}
{"data":{"@type":"cat"}}
```

Is it possible? How to do it?

I have tried with `enableDefaultTyping` but I get:

```
{"@type":"cat"}
{"data":["DemoJackson$Cat",{}]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are serializing a map directly, as you do, the object mapper needs the type information about the map contents because of generic typing. Please refer to chapter 5.1 of [Polymorphic Type Handling wiki page](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization).

An example of passing the type reference information when serializing the map of Animals.

```
objectMapper.writerWithType(new TypeReference<Map<String, Animal>>() {})
    .writeValueAsString(map)
```

Output:

```
{"@type":"cat"}
{"data":{"@type":"cat"}}
```

Comment: My real life scenario is more complex. I don't know in advance what is the kind of the object I have to serialize, but I have succeeded to make it working using an instanceof to know if I need to call writeWithType.